# Is anyway to deploy airflow on elastic bean stack (separate environments for web server, scheduler and worker)

Tags: deployment, airflow, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to set up airflow on AWS elastic beanstalk. Separate environments for the webserver, scheduler, and workers. So, each of them can be scaled independently.

Problem:

```
 1. How do we know the health of all the applications ( webserver, scheduler, and workers)? 
 2. Is there any better way to deploy airflow in prod env?
```

Motivation to deploy on AWS elastic beanstalk: If any of the servers gets down, AWS will manage the server and spin up a new server/servers.

Currently, I am running webserver, scheduler, and workers on one ec2 machine. I am running all these as follows: airflow webserver, airflow scheduler, airflow worker respectively. I am across "/health" (https://airflow.apache.org/howto/check-health.html). But it has a health check for scheduler and metadatabase. But this endpoint is showing unhealthy for the scheduler, even when the scheduler is running.